# Create "Signed Public Key And Challenge" (SPKAC) with .NET

Tags: .net, cryptography, x509, spkac

Is it possible to create an SPKAC (signed public key and challenge) with .NET *without* the use of OpenSSL? I know that OpenSSL can do this, but for this project I need to avoid third-party libraries.

Actually I want to do what the HTML5 `<keygen>` element does. The [corresponding MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/keygen) says the following:

> The public key and challenge string are DER encoded as PublicKeyAndChallenge, and then digitally signed with the private key to produce a SignedPublicKeyAndChallenge. The SignedPublicKeyAndChallenge is base64 encoded, and the ASCII data is finally submitted to the server *[...]*

We have a server that returns client certificates when an SPKAC is submitted and I want to copy the browser's behavior for automatic certificate retrieving.

Does anyone know how to do this?